# How to coerce a corpus to be assessed on the same terms as another one

Tags: r, nlp

## Problem

I need to have a corpus of text, applied the same terms as another, so I can get a term document matrix with the same values.
What I am attempting, is to classify different corpus of texts between 2 groups, using a logistic regression, but I need both of these corpus to have the same variables from the function `DocumentTermMatrix()`.

## Current attempt and explanation with code

I can't wrap my head about how to approach the issue, for example, this gives me a first matrix of terms with their frequency:

```
data("crude")
crude_1 <- crude[1:10]
dtm_1 <- DocumentTermMatrix(crude_1)
dtm_1$dimnames$Terms
#  [1] "..."               "\"(it)"            "\"demand"          "\"for"            
#  [5] "\"growth"          "\"if"              "\"is"              "\"may" ...
```

How can I use the same terms for the second part of the `crude` dataset, because so far the Terms are different:

```
crude_2 <- crude[11:20]
dtm_2 <- DocumentTermMatrix(crude_2)
dtm_2$dimnames$Terms
#  [1] "..."             "\"expansion"     "\"is"            "\"may"          
#  [5] "\"none"          "\"this"          "\"we"            "\"will" ...
```

I could try to run a frequency on the same terms on `crude_2`. However, it would be expensive in terms of computation, and you might know a practical solution to this problem.

## Question

I would like to coerce `dtm_2` to have the same terms as in `dtm_1`. Only with the frequency of the `crude_2` dataset. Is there a practical way to do this in R ?

**Or more easily for example: Say I want to find out, how many times `zebra` or `girafe` appears in these text, and I want to do it explicitly, how can I proceed ?**

Libraries used: `library(tm)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found a solution to my question by using the function [`tm_term_score()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tm/versions/0.7-8/topics/tm_term_score) from the package `tm` and it works well I'd say, though any different implementation would be welcome.

## Normal solution

This is the solution, first we capture the terms in a separate variable and then we apply the term list to create a matrix upon the other Document Term Matrix with the workds frequency:

```
data("crude")
# First dataset and term list
crude_1 <- crude[1:10]
dtm_1 <- DocumentTermMatrix(crude_1)
term_list <- dtm_1$dimnames$Terms

# Second dataset
crude_2 <- crude[11:20]
dtm_2 <- DocumentTermMatrix(crude_2)

# Creating a dummy column to remove at the end
X <- data.frame(dummy_col = 1:dtm_2$nrow)
for (term in term_list) {
    temp_col <- tm_term_score(dtm_2, term)
    # Attaching the column to the DF
    X$temp_col<-temp_col
    names(X)[length(names(X))] <- term
}
# Removing the dummy column
X$dummy_col <- NULL
# The variable X now contains the term frequency of the first data set, but applied to the second
```

## Specific terms

And if you are looking for specific terms (like `zebra` or `girafe`, which there are none here), you can do as follow:

```
term_list <- c("zebra", "girafe")
X <- data.frame(dummy_col = 1:dtm_2$nrow)
for (term in term_list) {
    temp_col <- tm_term_score(dtm_2, term)
    # Attaching the column to the DF
    X$temp_col<-temp_col
    names(X)[length(names(X))] <- term
}
X$dummy_col <- NULL
X
#        zebra girafe
# 1      0      0
# 2      0      0
# 3      0      0
# ...
```